# Index corrupted after restore PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, indexing, corrupt, wal-e

We use WAL-E to backup and restore a PostgreSQL database (version 9.5.13), We found that a few indexes (not all) were broken after restored, most of them are related to String type fields.

For example, using *analyze explain* we can see the following query hits an existing index which relates to *foo_name* field, but no rows returns.

```
select * from foo where foo_name = 'xyz';
```

If we use like in the query, it is able to return the expected row because it performs full-table scan.

```
select * from foo where foo_name like '%xyz%';
```

The solution is to reindex the broken indexes. After we reindex it, the first query also returns the expected result.

Does anyone meet the same issue before? Does anyone have any idea on the root cause?

Comment: Something sounds fishy here.  An index should _not_ have any bearing on the logical result of a SQL query, at least not in Postgres.

Comment: What is "WAL-E"? How did you restore your database? If you have a problem with the indices, why not rebuild all of them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the version is 9.5.13

Comment: @NicoHaase see the link for wal-e: https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e .

Comment: Indexes are not portable across systems, because collations aren't, unless using `collate "C"` or ICU. Are you restoring into a different OS?

Comment: @DanielVérité Sometimes it is enough to [restore to a different version of the same operating system to get index corruption](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CB4D1C6BAA80CF146CB0D4F2%40eje.credativ.lan).